# ng-class not working. Where did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I know there are many problems here listed like this. but I can't pinpoint where I did wrong..

```
<li ng-repeat="item in type.sub | orderBy:y" ng-click="openpic($parent.$index, $index)" ng-class="{ 'active': $parent.$index + ':' + $index == current }">
```

we have `$scope.current` variable, and a nested menu with numbering id like 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 2:1, 2:2, 2:3 and so on.

Goal is very simple. I need to make this `<li>` active, if the `$parent.$index:$index` is equal to `$scope.current`. ID is set whenever `openpic($parent.$index, $index)` triggered. We have `li.active` class in css.

So, can someone please show me, what's missing in that code?

### TRY 1:

Tried:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in type.sub | orderBy:y" ng-click="openpic($parent.$index, $index)" ng-class="{ 'active': $parent.$index + ':' + $index == $parent.current }">
```

Still not working.

### TRY 2

I have something like this:

```
ng-class="{{ $parent.$index + ':' + $index == $parent.current && 'active' || '' }}"
```

and it shows as `ng-class="active"` but `class` attribute did not updated.

### TRY 3

```
ng-class="{{ $parent.$index + ':' + $index == $parent.current && 'highlight' || '' }}"
```

it shows `ng-class='highlight"`, but class still shows `class="ng-binding ng-scope"`

### TRY 4

```
ng-class="isActive($parent.$index,$index)"
```

It solves the problem, but it seems a little bit overkill for a simple switch function. Any more ideas?

### TRY 5

As per major-mann code suggestion that works at TRY 4, I made these adjustment, and surprisingly, it works.

```
ng-class="$parent.$index + ':' + $index == $parent.current && 'active' || ''"
```

That one works. Removed all braces completely ????

Comment: In which scope is defined var 'current' ? If it is in your controller scope, maybe you meant to write $parent.current ?
Also try debugging by writing for example <li>{{ $parent.$index + ':' + $index }}</li>

Comment: yes.. in controller $scope. Let me try

Comment: Not working.. updated at code

Comment: As an alternative, you can write a function within your scope to return you the classname.

Comment: If you write something like <li>{{ $parent.$index + ':' + $index }} VS {{ current }}</li> you will find what is going wrong because i think your ng-class is correct

Comment: Your last edit made me think of this : as 'active' class is used in some frameworks, you should check if there is no interference between your ng-class and other JS code of the framework, removing the 'active' class if the element is not focused or something like that. So I advise you to try with another class, let's say .test { background-color: pink; }, and try to apply 'test' class in your ng-class

Comment: A bit of a non-answer, but as a general rule, I make functions in my controller to manage things like concatenation, and then call those functions in the view (eg. `ng-class="isActive($parent.$index, $index)"`) I have found this makes debugging infinitely simpler.

Comment: I definitely don't have 'active' class, but let me check.

Comment: major-mann.. that solves the problem. If you put it as answer, I will select it.

Comment: You have mentioned any ng-repeat for li parent, if you mentioned then only $parent.$index will work otherwise it wont work......

Comment: I have parent ng-repeat. major-mann's solution works, but a little overkill. It works nonetheless

Comment: Ok.. as per major-mann code, I've made an edit with working code.

Comment: @major-mann can you please put your comment as answer? So I can accept it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed to in the comments, rather a non-answer, but usually it is best practice to try to keep code (even simple ternaries) inside the JavaScript blocks rather than inside the HTML. This generally makes debugging any issues you may be having infinitely easier to deal with.

So, for example, you could change your HTML to something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="..." ng-click="..." ng-class="isActive($parent.$index, $index)">
```

And in your controller, you could add something like:

```
$scope.menu= function isActive(pidx, idx) {
    return {
        active: pidx + ':' + idx === $scope.current
    };
};
```

To achieve your desired result.

If you take this a step further, you will probably realize that it is even better to do something like

```
$scope.cls.menu = function(pidx, idx) {
    return {
        active: pidx + ':' + idx === $scope.current,
        any: 'other',
        dynamic: 'classes',
        you: 'need'
    };
}
```

And call the function appropriately in the view.

Comment: Actually, it is ng-class="isActive($parent.$index, $index)" that gave me the idea. Not isActive function itself.

Answer (score 2):

First of all make `{{$parent.$index:$index}}` to make sure to get the right data (I just never met such a method to data access) ;
If it's ok, then try use:

```
ng-class="$parent.$index:$index === current ? 'active' : ''"
```

Or (best way) use function for this:

```
ng-class="someFn($parent.$index)"
```

```
$scope.someFn = function(index){
    //index, index:index, index[n] or something else;
    return index === $scope.current ? 'active' : '';
};
```

**Update:**
If  You want get access to parent `ng-repeat`, better use

```thml
<...  ng-repeat="(index1, data1) in firstData">
    <...  ng-repeat="(index2, data2) in secondData">
        <... ng-something="index1 operator index2 or function(index1, index2)">
```

I hope, it will help;

Comment: Yes, it works. But major-mann has pointed the same thing first. Sorry for not awarding the answer to you. I am waiting for him make his comment as answer, and i will pick it  I think that only fair.

Comment: @Magician I completely agree =)